# std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point cast to store in SQLite?

Tags: c++, sqlite, c++11, time, c++-chrono

I have a:

```
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point TP;
```

I populate some member variables like:

```
this->setPlantStartedGrowingTime(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());

this->setEstimatedPlantStoppedGrowingTime(getPlantStartedGrowingTime() +
                                          std::chrono::seconds(getGrowTime()));
```

Now, I need to store this in SQLite. But I cannot see how to convert this to an int or real data type to store.

Update: I know about `time_since_epoch()` but documentation says: "Returns a duration object with the time span value between the epoch and the time point. The value returned is the current value of the internal duration object."

Comment: `time_point::time_since_epoch()`

Comment: @Brian - I dont want an interval though. I want, when I set `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` to also get that value in real or Integer so I can store it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand what time_since_epoch() is actually going to return. Let me see what `.time_since_epoch().count()` returns.